# how to change the custom option value to download link in magento 2 order

Tags: magento2, product, orders, product-images, custom-options

> Hi I have created **a custom option** for product

[image: Custom option for product]

> working fine in the front end
>
> When I order this product
>
> in  order view the product custom option showing as text
>
> **I need as the download link**
>
> How I can do this????
>   [image]

Comment: hello, @prabhakaran7 May I know which Magento 2 version are you using? As I have checked in Magento 2.3.1 its working fine.

Comment: Magento 2.2.6  ....

Comment: you got any solutions?

Comment: nope you have any idea

Comment: no, stucked at same point :(

Comment: which magento version your using